# An orthogonal projection matrix in $ \Bbb{R}^{3} $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, orthogonality

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R^3}$ with usual inner product. Find the orthogonal projection matrix on the xy plane.

I've found sometimes the orthogonal projection of a vector in a given subspace, but in this case I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: It is the orthogonal projection on the subspace with equation $z=0$, or the subspace generated  by the orthogonal basis $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: In general, if $U=[u_1|\cdots|u_r]$ where $\{u_1,\cdots, u_r\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the subspace, then you can take $P=UU^{T}$.

Comment: @user84413 How can I determine the orthogonal projection of a vector onto a subspace?

Comment: You can take $Pv$, where P is the projection matrix.  Equivalently, you can take $\vec{p}=\langle v,u_1\rangle u_1+\cdots+\langle v,u_r\rangle u_r$ where $\{u_1,\cdots,u_r\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two vectors $e_x$ and $e_y$ are invariant under the projection, and the last one is mapped to 0.

Hence the columns of the matrix are, in order;

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0 \\0
\end{pmatrix} ;
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1 \\0
\end{pmatrix} ;
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 0 \\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Why $e_x$ and $e_y$ are invariant under the projection?  In order to use the information on the inner product?

Comment: it is the projection on the plane generated by the vectors $e_x$ and $e_y$. So they are invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is just asking you to think about what happens. If you project onto the xy plane you will have a $z=0$ component

i.e. you will have your vector multiplied by a matrix of the form

$$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

Is this all that you are looking for?

Comment: What is the general procedure to find an matrix of orthogonal projection?

Comment: You could take a look at what happens to the basis vectors under the linear transformation and the coordinates would form the matrix